# How to create a custom type converter from an open generic to a simple generic with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a class that implements the option monad from functional program languages. The implementation is very simple:

```
public class Maybe<T> : IMaybe<T>
{
  public T Value { get; set; } = default!;
  public bool IsDefined { get; set; }
  // Other methods that aren't relevant
}
```

I would like to define an automapper configuration so that when a `Maybe<T>` is mapped to a `T`, the `Value` property of the `Maybe<T>` is returned.

The [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Open-Generics.html) only has cases where both sides of the mapping are open generics, however following that pattern I have defined a custom converter:

```
public class MaybeToUnwrappedConverter<TSource> : ITypeConverter<Maybe<TSource>, TSource>
{
  public TSource Convert(Maybe<TSource> source, TSource destination, ResolutionContext context) => source.Value;
}
```

And added a profile for it:

```
CreateMap(typeof(Maybe<>), typeof(object))
  .ConvertUsing(typeof(MaybeToUnwrappedConverter<>));
```

However on application launch an `Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for assignment to type ResourceAllocation` (`ResourceAllocation` is one of the DTOs in the project). I assume this is happening because AutoMapper's startup validation is using the type defined in the `CreateMap` rather than the runtime type returned from the converter.

Is there a way to configure AutoMapper to make this work?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/3981

Answer (score 0):

Posting this GitHub discussion provided by Lucian in the comments as the answer: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/discussions/3981

The recommendation there is to use a conversion operator, which AutoMapper can then use. In my case, I don't want to add a conversion operator for this type because there are semantic differences between `Empty` and `default` (differences that wouldn't have been as important for property mapping). So instead I will just be adding custom mappers where a type has a `Maybe<T>` being mapped to a `T`.